# Django: How to map different words to specific charfield entries (should be a simple answer)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a gender attribute of a model that is populated in my database with either the values "male" or "female". This model property is populated automatically with a function I made in the views.py file for scraping the gender of a selected person using the facebook API. So the value stored in the gender field will be either "male" or "female" since facebook requires each user to pick a binary gender. However, I want all my template tags of the form {{ Model.gender }} to return "hippopotamus" if the field is populated with male or "elephant" if the field is populated with female. I thought I could do this by using the choice field option in the model settings, but no luck. So basically, what's the easiest way to map "hippopotamus" to "male" and "elephant" to "female"? 
Thanks in advance.

```
 class Model(models.Model):
      gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=(('male', 'hippopotamus'), ('female', 'elephant')), blank=True, null=True)
```

EDIT: I should clarify that I know how to do this using conditional statements in the template, but was wondering if there was any django method to do the mapping on the backend itself. I know a solution to this issue can simply be:

```
 {% if Model.gender == "male" %}
 Hippopotamus
 {% else %}
 Elephant
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display):

> For every field that has choices set, the object will have a
>   get_FOO_display() method, where FOO is the name of the field. This
>   method returns the “human-readable” value of the field.

In template you should use like this:

```
{{ model_instance.get_gender_display }}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was wondering. Thanks! I don't know why I missed that part in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a very simple way to do that in the backend.
In your function that load the view you want, you can do this filtering with the idea of the conditional operator of python.

```
value = b if a > 10 else c
```

I believe you have something like this to load you view in views.py:

```
def index(request):
    #You are filtering the model here maybe
    render(request, 'index.html', {'Model' : model});
```

Since the model that you filtered is already an object, you can send all the variables already set to the view by the dictionary parameter (3rd parameter of the render function).
So you can have something like that:

```
def index(request):
    model = #Filter to get the model you want
    gender = "Hippopotamus" if model.gender == "male" else "Elephant"
    render(request, 'index.html' {'gender': gender,})
```

If you don't know how to use the render function and its dictionary you read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

Comment: This is sort of what I meant, and technically correct, but I think the other post is slightly more elegant.

Comment: Ok, no problem @SwAvGuy :D